# PySpark replace Matches with Uppercase

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, regexp-replace

I have a long list words that I would like to emphasize by capitalizing them when they appear in my data description fields. So far I have been able to emphasize them by surrounding them with special characters "*KEYWORD*" but have not been able to figure out how to implement the replace with uppercase "[\U$1\E](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html)" syntax. Is this a feature that is not available on PySpark?

```
inputString = """
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. et
beatae perspiciatis et 
consequatur libero ut fuga 
quibusdam ut expedita quae qui
aspernatur culpa qui natus 
soluta qui neque perferendis. 
sit praesentium optio ut 
libero vitae sed dolor ipsa ut
corporis consequatur eum 
obcaecati quisquam nam iure 
assumenda? vel excepturi animi
est consequatur molestias ab 
necessitatibus nesciunt.
et inventore internos ea 
reprehenderit voluptatum ut 
vero quam. et quia incidunt 
est rerum natus et magnam ipsa
et autem consequatur et velit
placeat aut maxime corrupti 
""".split('\n')


sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'value': inputString }))

matchSet = "(libero|dolor|quia|inventore)"

sparkDF.withColumn('value', F.regexp_replace('value', matchSet, '*$1*')).show(truncate = 50)

+----------------------------------+
|                             value|
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
|  lorem ipsum *dolor* sit amet. et|
|           beatae perspiciatis et |
|     consequatur *libero* ut fuga |
|    quibusdam ut expedita quae qui|
|       aspernatur culpa qui natus |
|    soluta qui neque perferendis. |
|         sit praesentium optio ut |
|*libero* vitae sed *dolor* ipsa ut|
|         corporis consequatur eum |
|      obcaecati quisquam nam iure |
|    assumenda? vel excepturi animi|
|     est consequatur molestias ab |
|          necessitatibus nesciunt.|
|       et *inventore* internos ea |
|      reprehenderit voluptatum ut |
|    vero quam. et *quia* incidunt |
|    est rerum natus et magnam ipsa|
|     et autem consequatur et velit|
|      placeat aut maxime corrupti |
+----------------------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, split the strings using delimiter then transform the values that belongs to matchSet to uppercase using `upper` finally join the strings back using `array_join`

```
matchSet = ['libero', 'dolor', 'quia', 'inventore']
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn(
    'col', 
    F.array_join(
        F.transform(
            F.split('value', ' '), 
            lambda s: F.when(s.isin(matchSet), F.upper(s)).otherwise(s)
        ), ' '
    )
)
```

Result

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|value                         |col                           |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                              |                              |
|lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. et|lorem ipsum DOLOR sit amet. et|
|beatae perspiciatis et        |beatae perspiciatis et        |
|consequatur libero ut fuga    |consequatur LIBERO ut fuga    |
|quibusdam ut expedita quae qui|quibusdam ut expedita quae qui|
|aspernatur culpa qui natus    |aspernatur culpa qui natus    |
|soluta qui neque perferendis. |soluta qui neque perferendis. |
|sit praesentium optio ut      |sit praesentium optio ut      |
|libero vitae sed dolor ipsa ut|LIBERO vitae sed DOLOR ipsa ut|
|corporis consequatur eum      |corporis consequatur eum      |
|obcaecati quisquam nam iure   |obcaecati quisquam nam iure   |
|assumenda? vel excepturi animi|assumenda? vel excepturi animi|
|est consequatur molestias ab  |est consequatur molestias ab  |
|necessitatibus nesciunt.      |necessitatibus nesciunt.      |
|et inventore internos ea      |et INVENTORE internos ea      |
|reprehenderit voluptatum ut   |reprehenderit voluptatum ut   |
|vero quam. et quia incidunt   |vero quam. et QUIA incidunt   |
|est rerum natus et magnam ipsa|est rerum natus et magnam ipsa|
|et autem consequatur et velit |et autem consequatur et velit |
|placeat aut maxime corrupti   |placeat aut maxime corrupti   |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```